# FlexSlider images causes the page to expands over width

Tags: jquery, css

As the subject says- the flex slider image are on display: block state
and the paging(numbers only) appear on the left of the page.

what is the right state of the images when they are not active?
I have tried to give them display: none but it didn't help.

any suggestions? how can i solve it?

[image]

Comment: have you tried to setting `display:none;` to the `<li>` of the `<img>`? you can too, try a `display:none !important;` to override all possible occurrences of `display`.

Comment: yes but do you know where i should apply it? i don't seem to find the place

Comment: `$('#slides li').eq(5).css('display','none');`